# How to copy from one split and paste in another in byobu?

Tags: vim, terminal, split, copy-paste, byobu

So let's say I have two splits open in byobu, side by side. Furthermore, both splits have different files open in vim. I want to highlight text from one file in one split and copy it to a separate file in the other split. Any ideas?

All the results I found while searching for this talked about using the scrollback feature to copy and paste in byobu, however, that only seems to work inside a single split; not across splits.

Comment: Why don't you simply open the two files in Vim?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like I posted to quickly; seemed to have found the solution. I followed the steps found here:

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_termmux.php

I followed the steps:

`shift-f3` - move to split to be copied from

`alt-pgup` - enter copy mode

`space`    - start selection

cursor through desired text

`enter`    - end selection

`shift-f3` - shift focus to split to copy to

ensure receiving vim is in insert mode

`alt-insert` - paste selected text

Comment: I've only used tmux and screen without byobu, so maybe I'm missing something, but I'm guessing the pasting part of this procedure could wreak havoc on Vim if you're not careful. Specifically, you need to make sure the receiving Vim is in insert mode; and you'd probably want to do `:set paste` beforehand and `:set nopaste` afterwards, so your indentation doesn't get messed up. See my answer for a nicer way.

Comment: You are correct that the receiving Vim has to be in insert mode. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an X Window Server, an alternative mouse-based solution to using the scrollback mode (which involves remembering a lot of keystrokes) is:

1. Zoom in on the current pane (Shift-F11), bringing this pane to the foreground.
2. You can now select the relevant text with your mouse without the vertical split getting in the way.
3. Unzoom the pane (Shift-F11 again)
4. Switch to other pane or wherever else you want to paste.
5. Middle click paste.

Comment: This also works when accessing remotely (e.g. ssh) but, for whatever reason, I need to hold shift when selecting the text.

Answer (score 2):

If your Vim supports the system clipboard (i.e. if `vim --version` output shows `+clipboard`), you can copy into the system clipboard from the first Vim and paste from it into the second one. This releaves us of the need to ensure the receiving Vim is in insert mode and has `paste` set appropriately.

The trick is to use the `"+` register. So when you do the copy, prefix whatever yanking command you want to use with `"+`; and do likewise prefix the put command you use in the receiving Vim with it.

If you're on an X11 system, you can also use the `"*` register, which is X's "PRIMARY" selection buffer -- the one where text goes if you just highlight it, and which you can paste by pressing the middle button.

See [`:help gui-selections`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#gui-selections). GUI selection support generally requires a Vim other than "vim-tiny"; on Debian and Ubuntu the vim-gtk and vim-gnome packages are good choices.