# Straightforward way of copying text from byobu to system clipboard?

Tags: copy-paste, byobu

I frequently want to copy snippets of command outputs to the web browser. Doing so is nice and simple in gnome-terminal (mouse-select, right-click, copy) but seems to be not so straightforwardly possible in byobu.

The procedure for copying outlined in the docs is:
Enter scrollback using  alt-pgup or  alt-pgdn,  press  the  spacebar  to start highlighting text, use up/down/left/right/pgup/pgdn to select the text, and press enter to copy the
text. You can then paste the text using alt-insert or ctrl-a-].

However, this doesn't copy to system clipboard (and seems to involve quite a few keystrokes)

This source suggests using xsel
https://askubuntu.com/questions/33789/how-do-i-integrate-byobus-copy-buffer-with-the-x-clipboard
which doesn't work for me and would be rather less convenient anyway(what if I want to scroll up to several commands earlier that ran in a different context?)

What I would like is, ideally, a way to copy to the system clipboard that works in the same as gnome-terminal eg. highlight -> ctrl+shift+c or right-click copy or some way to integrate the byobu copy buffer with the system copy buffer.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome and byobu 5.106-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923952/how-to-copy-from-one-split-and-paste-in-another-in-byobu#comment86150928_35329659), holding the shift key seems to be the solution to your problem. So:

- **Shift**+F11 to zoom in on the split that you want to copy from
- **Shift**+select what you want to copy
- **Shift**+right click, copy (or by the way, Shift+Ctrl+C that also works in gnome-terminal)

Comment: Hi thanks for response.
This works for allowing me to select and copy less than one line of text. If I try and copy multiple lines then the text will be copied across the boundaries of the different virtual terminal splits I have running.

But reading on in that thread you link to, this can work if I zoom in on the current split with shift+F11

good enough :)

Comment: I can't believe that it took me 15 minutes to find an answer that actually worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues when selecting command outputs bigger than an entire screen, mouse select may be harder on these cases. My preferred method is to use <shift+F7> to capture output from desired split to a new PRINTSCREEN.

After that I select the desired portion of output at PRINTSCREEN using editor shortcuts and then getting it into system clipboard (e.g. using vim select then "+gy).